# transfer images from folder to another folder in python

Tags: python

Suppose I have an array of images_id, and I have a folder of images, I want to transfer some images  from the folder to a new folder based on the array.

Right now my code is

```
import shutil
for i in new_id:
    path = images_folder + i
    dest = '/content/train/image/' + i
    os.rename(path, dest)
    os.replace(path, dest)
    shutil.move(path, dest)
```

But my error is
No such file or directory: '/content/train/img_align_celeba/img_align_celeba/058713.jpg' -> '/content/train/image/058713.jpg

I tried another code

```
import pandas as pd
import os

def move_file(old_file_path, new_directory):
    if not os.path.isdir(new_directory):
        os.mkdir(new_directory)
    base_name = os.path.basename(old_file_path)
    new_file_path = os.path.join(new_directory, base_name)
    # Deletes a file if that file already exists there, you can change this behavior
    if os.path.exists(new_file_path):
        os.remove(new_file_path)
    os.rename(old_file_path, new_file_path)

cop_folder = images_folder

destination_folder = '/content/train/image/'

#df = pd.read_csv('files.csv', header=None)

for i in new_id:
 #   filename = os.path.join(cop_folder, i)
    filename = os.path.join(cop_folder, i)
    move_file(filename, destination_folder)
```

The error is
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/train/img_align_celeba/img_align_celeba/058713.jpg' -> '/content/train/image/058713.jpg'

Comment: Are you intending to double this directory? img_align_celeba/img_align_celeba

Comment: in general `'/content/'` will look for a root folder called `content`. `'./content/'` will look for a folder in the current working directory (`print(os.getcwd())`) called `content`. I would take a look at the pathlib module. It makes this sort of thing much more reliable.

Comment: Why do you have `os.rename`, `os.replace`, and `shutil.move`?  After you do the `rename`, the original file no longer exists and the other two will fail.

Comment: img_align_celeba/img_align_celeba is a nested folder path; os.rename/replace/shutil.move is from another answer.

Comment: I comment "os.rename" but still the same error.